# Drupal: a question about t() function

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I've added the following text in the t() function in page.tpl.php page.

```
<?php echo t('Some random text to translate.'); ?>
```

Now when I go to admin/build/translate/search to translate the string drupal cannot find it.

I've refreshed all caches, and also the "Refresh" tab in internationalization module.

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [t() function](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/t/6), to save on performance for single-language sites, won't store the string in the database until it is requested from another language. View the page in one of the non-default languages in order to populate the database (t() calls [locale() to do this](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--locale--locale.module/function/locale/6)), thus making the string available for translation.